# Change outlook mailitem selection c#

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, mailitem

I want to select a mailItem from my outlook add-in.
I know how to display a mailitem from c# but I need to select it inside the outlook window itself.

Display a mailitem:

```
mailItem.Display();
```

I am using the Outlook 2010 Add-in.

Anybody has any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Explorer.ClearSelection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862680.aspx) and then [`Explorer.AddToSelection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868732.aspx). You should use [`Explorer.IsItemSelectableInView()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868297.aspx) before calling `AddToSelection()` to ensure the item you want to select exists in the current explorer view.

[`Application.ActiveExplorer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff870017.aspx) will give you the current active explorer if it exists.

Here is a [sample snippet taken from here](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=8587) (*slightly modified to check `IsItemSelectableInView`*).

```cs
Outlook._Explorer explorer = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer();  // get active explorer
explorer.ClearSelection(); // remove current selection
Outlook.NameSpace ns = OutlookApp.Session; 
object item = ns.GetItemFromID(entryId, Type.Missing); // retrieve item
if (explorer.IsItemSelectableInView(item)) // ensure item is in current view
  explorer.AddToSelection(item); // change explorer selection
else
  // TODO: change current view so that item is selectable
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item); 
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns); 
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(explorer);
```

To change the current `Explorer` view you can use [`Explorer.CurrentFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866719.aspx) or [`Explorer.CurrentView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861617.aspx)

Comment: Sweet man :) thx! (srr for the late response but I was busy with other stuff)

Comment: The function Application.ActiveExplorer() will not work under Conversation View

Comment: Where are you getting OutlookApp from?

Comment: @StevenByrne It's just a namespace alias for readabilty.... `using OutlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;`